# Issues binding @Html.LabelFor and @Html.DropDownListFor MVC5

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, label, accessibility, form-control

I have a @Html.DropDownListFor for my form-control that has multiple countries to choose from in a drop down menu. I need this form-control to be ADA compliant, so I need to have a label associated with it. This is the form-control:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ShippingCountry, Model.Countries, "Please select a country",
new
{
    @id = "ShippingCountry",
    @name = "ShippingCountry",
    @class = "w100",
    @title = "Shipping Countries"
})
```

Using something like `@Html.labelFor("ShippingCountry")` or `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ShippingCountry)` does not pass the ADA compliance tests according to the Web Accessibility Evaluation Tool (WAVE).

Is there a specific way to bind labels and form controls such as DropDownListFor in MVC5 using Razor code? Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: What test does it fail? (and as a side note, remove the the pointless `@id = "ShippingCountry",` and `@name = "ShippingCountry",` - the method already adds the correct `name` and `id` attributes, and the `@name=".."` is ignored anyway)

Comment: Running the Chrome WAVE tool extension produces "A form control does not have a corresponding label" error.

Comment: Then there is a problem with the tool, because `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ShippingCountry)` **DOES** produce a corresponding label (it will generate `<label for="ShippingCountry">...</label>`

Comment: Possibly. When you add something like '@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ShippingCountry)' the tool says that the label produced is associated with a form, but then it still says that the form is not associated with a label. The tool works perfectly with regular html. The only issues are with the razor code portions with '@Html.DropDownListFor'